# Transmission object render fail

Tags: modeling, rendering, glass

Below is what i rendered :
[image]

As you can see, the glass bit on the down left of the object is super distorted
[image]
Above is the object material properties window. I just used transmission feature to achieve the glass texture.
On the grey and white cubes that the 'glass' object goes through, boolean modifier is applied.
on the 'glass' object, no modifier is applied.

What could be possibly causing that distortion? Also I am making that glass texture so that the inner structure of this cassette player is visible. What other ways would you recommend to do this?

Thank you all beforehand, lmk if you need me to elaborate on anything

Comment: The glass is a solid cube here?  There is an interaction on both the front and backfacing ray collisions that takes IOR into account.

Comment: Thinner glass panes are a thing to try, and you can always cheat by lowering IOR